# How to prevent Powershell from overwriting the output of a c++ program that uses AttachConsole() after it has finished

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, user-interface, console

I am trying to write a c++ program that can be launched by double clicking the executable from e.g. explorer, or alternatively can be called from a commandline such as powershell or cmd.

I want the application to not open a console when called from a gui environment (clicking in explorer, a desktop shortcut, etc). I do want it to output to a console when called from a commandline to provide useful information to more technically inclined people.I'm pretty new to GUI stuff with c++ so please be gentle.

Details:

- c++ 23
- Using cmake and mingw to build,
- Using Clion to code.
- Using Windows 11.

I have looked for similar questions online but I have yet to find them.

I have a working example that achieves this, It behaves as expected in cmd, but when running it in Powershell, Powershell will overwrite the output after the program has finished, as if the program never printed lines to the console. (see pictures for examples). The funny thing is that Powershell does work as expected when I reach the bottom of the terminal. Due to the nature of this problem I will include pictures as I do not see a good alternative to show my issue. This code does not launch a GUI, but my final code does and exhibits the same problem.

Unrelated: it appears stdin is still going to powershell while attached.

Cmake config

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(consoletest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_executable(consoletest main.cpp)
target_link_options(consoletest PRIVATE -mwindows)
```

Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    // Attach output to console if called from console.
    AttachConsole(-1);
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

    std::cout << "\nHello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    // Send enter key hack for console mode to return to parent console
    INPUT ip;
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    ip.ki.wScan = VK_RETURN;
    ip.ki.wVk = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    return 0;
}
```

Images:

[Powershell when there is space left below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Elw.png)

[Powershell with no space left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBeAU.png)

[CMD works as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqRWx.png)

**Edit:**
The solution from @mklement0 will do for my purposes. I do still wish there is a way to have the program do this automatically without needing additional effort when calling the program. When using the methods from @mklement0, you no longer need the "Enter hack" or the \n in the first `cout`.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the problem is? The only difference between your screenshots is one is missing the prompt/file path? If you hit enter it should show up again

Comment: @jeremywat the problem is that the "3rd" prompt line in the first picture has overwritten the first output line of the program. There should be 7 "hello world" lines. When you type after the program has finished you will start typing on the 3rd line and will gradually wipe all the program's output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `cmd.exe`, **PowerShell by default *always*<sup>[1]</sup> launches Windows GUI-subsystem applications *asynchronously***, which results in the symptoms you saw.

To **ensure *synchronous* execution of an application that explicitly attaches to the caller's console and writes to it, pipe to `Write-Output`**:

```bash
.\consoletest.exe | Write-Output
```

This approach, as well as all subsequent ones, **obviate the need for your attempt to programmatically send a <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke**, because the synchronous execution ensures that the PowerShell doesn't return to and prints its prompt string until after execution has ended.

**If only ever *display* output is needed**, you may also use `Write-Host`, or using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process):

```bash
# Display output only; output cannot be captured.
Start-Process -NoNewWindow -Wait .\consoletest.exe
```

It is the involvement of a **pipeline by itself that makes the call synchronous**, so you **may use this technique for *any* GUI application**, even those that do *not* attach to the console, in case you can pipe to [`Out-Null`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null) (though piping to `Write-Host` or `Write-Output` would work too); e.g.

```bash
# Synchronous invocation of a GUI application that does *not* 
# attach to and write to the console.
Notepad | Out-Null
```

---

Alternatively, **if you (also) want to *capture* your application's output**:

To capture while also printing to the console, use [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object); adding redirection `2>&1` allows you to capture *stderr* output too:

```bash
# After this, $output contains contains the collected output.
.\consoletest.exe 2>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable output
```

To capture only (without console output):

```bash
$output = .\consoletestexe 2>&1 | Write-Output
```

In either case, if you later want to separate the stdout from the stderr output lines:

```bash
$stdoutLines, $stderrLines = $output.Where({ $_ -is [string] }, 'Split'})
```

---

If you want to write a ***wrapper command* (function) that invokes your application synchronously *without extra effort***:

```bash
function consoletest {
  # Use the executable's full path:
  # You can determine it programmatically with:
  #     Convert-Path .\consoletest.exe
  # If you want the function to look in the *current* dir. for
  # the executable, use .\consoletest.exe
  # $args passes any arguments through.
  & 'C:\path\to\consoletest.exe' $args 2>&1 | Write-Output
}
```

If you place this function in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file, it'll be available in all future sessions (except those started with `-NoProfile`).

---

<sup>[1] *Interactively*, `cmd.exe` executes GUI-subsystem applications *asynchronously*, whereas it does so *synchronously* *from batch files* and when passing commands to *`cmd.exe /c`*.

As you note, to also make interactive invocation synchronous, you can use `start /wait consoletest.exe` - unlike PowerShell's `Start-Process -Wait` analog, this does *not* preclude output capturing in `cmd.exe`, via `for /f`</sup>

Comment: I'll also add that a similar thing can be done with CMD by using `start /wait consoletest.exe` and then the "Enter hack"  and \n in the first cout can be removed.

Comment: Thanks, @Zwamdurkel; I've updated the answer to include this information.